# Integral convergent calculating

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have to calculate if this integral is convergent for any "$a$":

$$ \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x\log^a(x)} dx $$

(I made sure to not make any mistake when writing the integral from paper into this forums!)

I really don't what is meant by this..

Comment: Find out whether there is an $a$ such that the integral converges. Hint: substitute $u = \log x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing variable to $t=\log x$, one has
$$
\int_2^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x\log^{\alpha} x}\textrm{d}x=\int_{\log 2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t^{\alpha} }\textrm{d}t,
$$
so the integral converges if $\alpha>1$, diverges if $\alpha\le 1$.